# Using design frameworks for teams

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-teams, fluentui-react

We are building our web app and want to choose right design frameworks. Our plan is to build a stand alone web application and then to integrate it with Microsoft Teams. As I understand, web applications integrate with Teams using IFrame.

In the documentation for Teams developers is written that if I want to develop my web app inside Teams (as Teams web app), it is recommended to use Fluent UI Northstar. But if I want to develop just a stand alone web application and then to integrate with Teams, could I use other frameworks like Bootstrap, React bootstrap or Syncfusion? Are there any constraints while integrating with Teams?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms, as you've said, a tab is just a web page iframed into Teams. The only major requirement is that it reference the Teams javascript SDK and reference the [Javascript SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/msteams-client?view=msteams-client-js-latest&preserve-view=true), calling

```
microsoftTeams.initialize();
```

You can read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/content-page#integrate-your-code-with-teams).

As a result, you can use any web development technology (ASP.Net, php, node, etc.) and use/not use any front end development or design framework. I've built in the past, for example, tabs using jQuery and Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any web development technology as suggested by Hilton.
You can also use Fluent UI for web application development.

Reference link:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web